# Add bulk products drupal commerce: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() en form_type_checkboxes_value() line 2337 form.inc

Tags: commerce

I am workin on a commerce site and every product has many attributes and there are many combinations for each display. I am using [Commerce Bulk Product Creation](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_bpc) so I can add products quicly. The problem is that when I try to add many products in one shoot using this module I have a white screen and The warnng is:
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in form_type_checkboxes_value() (lne 2337 de xxx/includes/form.inc).
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because I am creating too many products at once. Not supported by the database or the hosting. It colapses and the foreach sends the warning. The result was a white screen.